# progress dialog for downloading pics

Tags: android, progress

I am downloading roughly 231 pics and would like to have a progress dialog say downloading pics please wait until all the pics are available and then disappear. How would I go about doing this?

```
protected class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url)
    {
        int count;
        try 
        {
            URL url1 = new URL(url[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url1.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();

            // download the file
            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url1.openStream());
            byte data[] = new byte[1024];

            long total = 0;
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) 
            {
                total += count;
                // publishing the progress....
                publishProgress((int)(total*100/lenghtOfFile));
            }
            input.close();
        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }
        return null;
    }
    public void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
    {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        // here you will have to update the progressbar
        // with something like
        setProgress(numPokemon);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please be specific to problem that you are facing

Comment: I have the progress dialog appear but it only stays visible while it downloads one pic making it ineffective

Comment: Then ur doing it wrong way show us code

Comment: Here is your solution check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog/3028660#3028660) one.

Answer (score 0):

I think u have dont wrong thing,
show progress dialog in onpreExecute() , ur logic in doinBackground() and dismiss progress dialog in onPostExecute().

Hope u get it

Answer (score 0):

**try this ::**

```
class AddTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
         ProgressDialog pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Recording.this,"Please wait...", "Retrieving data ...", true);
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            SaxParser(Username,Password);

        }

        protected Void doInBackground(Void... unused) {
           // your code
            return(null);
        }
        protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
      }
```